# Birt report viewer installation on glassfish

Tags: birt

I'm trying to set up an Birt report viewer (4.3.1) on a glassfish server(4).

The index page works, but when i try to run the test report , the browser gives me some text but not render the player. That doesn´t seems like an exception.

That's the screenshot:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3294352/www/BIRTPROBLEM.PNG

Seems like the path is incorrect (images, styles and js includes)... I did try to solve moving the files on applications folder (on glasshfish domain), but that's not working.

Please, help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34461-birt-glassfish/#entry127724

> I responded to a similar questions about this on the Eclipse BIRT Newsgroup a little while back. I saw the same issue with the frameset and run servlets. If you change the URL to preview, it works as expected. You could file a bug for this in the eclipse.org/birt bugzilla to see what they say.